# connecting 2 ftdi cables together

Tags: usb, ttl, ftdi

If I connect 2 FTDI cables together reversing tx and rx would I end up with a usb to usb cable ?

If so, I could connect a wireless FTDI adapter to a FTDI cable and get wireless usb.

Would I also need to alternat the CTS DTR lines ?

Answer (score 1):

> If I connect 2 FTDI cables together reversing tx and rx would I end up with a usb to usb cable ?

Not quite. You would end up with a cable that could talk to the other end via serial.

> If so, I could connect a wireless FTDI adapter to a FTDI cable and get wireless usb.

No, you would have wireless serial via USB.

> Would I also need to alternat the CTS DTR lines ?

That would depend on your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are two flavours of USB devices, those which can host, and those which can not.

Slave devices, such as the FTDI chips of which you speak cannot speak on the USB interface by themselves. They instead require a host device to control them - such as your PC. The net result of this is that two slave devices cannot talk to each other directly, and so no, you won't end up with a wireless USB hub because you won't be able to connect another slave device to your FTDI chip.

Furthermore, even if you connected some host device in there (such as the FTDI VDIP modules), you wouldn't immediately be able to make a wireless USB hub in this way. Why? because the software at the other end of the wireless link is expecting to talk to a USB device, not to a wireless serial port. There is a big distinction here, not just in the data throughput difference of USB vs UART, but also in the way they talk - USB is a master/slave bus, UART is asynchronous.

Now connecting the two FTDI chips together would allow you to create a USB to USB cable in the sense that it would allow you to connect two hosts together using your cable and allow them to speak to each other via a wireless virtual serial port link. But that is not the same as allowing a device to wirelessly access a USB slave device.